# How to redirect to the current searching page after update successfully?

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, laravel-8

How can I redirect to the current searching page after an update is successful?

Is there any idea where I can learn from? Already google it but can't find one...

#### Route:

```
  Route::get('/admin/usershiftpattern', 'Admin\UserShiftPatternController@index')->name('usp.index');
  Route::post('/admin/usershiftpattern/search', 'Admin\UserShiftPatternController@update')->name('usp.search');
```

#### Controller:

```
public function index(Request $req)
{
    $usershiftpattern = [];
    $shiftpattern = ShiftPattern::all();

    if($req->filled('searching')){
        $usershiftpattern = $this->fetch($req);
    }

    return view('admin.usershiftpattern', 
        ['usps' => $usershiftpattern], 
        compact('shiftpattern'));
}

public function update(Request $req)
{
    $usp_var = UserShiftPattern::find($req->inputid);
    $usp_var->shift_pattern_id = $req->inputShiftPatternID;
    $usp_var->sap_code = $req->inputSapCode;
    $execute = UserHelper::LogUserAct($req, "User Work Schedule", "Update User Work Schedule" .$req->inputid);
    $usp_var->save();
    return redirect(route('usp.index', [], false))->with([
        'feedback' => true,
        'feedback_text' => "User Shift Pattern ".$usp_var->shift_pattern_id." has successfully been updated.",
        'feedback_title' => "Successfully Updated"
    ]);
}
```

#### View:

```
<form action="{{ route('usp.search') }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <h4><b>Search User Work Schedule</b></h4>
```

Comment: Is your current code not working ? What is it doing ?

Comment: yes not work. after i click on update button,it go to main search page. i want it go to curremt search page

Comment: do this, replace `->back()` with `->route('ROUTE.NAME')`, `route.name` should be your search route's name.

Comment: It should be `usp.index` not `usp.search` = `->route('usp.index')`

Comment: Already update my question @matiaslauriti

Comment: @matiaslauriti already change as you told me and get the same error --> The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.

Comment: Do you want to go back to `usp.index` (it will display the search again) ? If so, you should be using `->route('usp.index')`. Try to do remove `redirect()` (I think it will give another error).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233891/discussion-between-daisy-and-matiaslauriti).

Comment: @matiaslauriti i already it and get same error --> The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.
yes i want it go back to the searching page which is in the usp.index
but right now, it go to the main searching which means no search at all
and it in the usp.index also

Comment: @matiaslauriti hye sir, do you have any idea? :D

Comment: Oh, I see your error, you are using the same method for both `post` and `get`... that is not okay. When you use `index`, it should be a `GET`, and when using `POST` you should be going to `store`. Share your complete controller please

Comment: @matiaslauriti i share the code inside the chat, because the code is long..

Comment: Don't worry, update your question with your code, without it we cannot do anything, the chat can get lost, but not your question content for anyone else to see

Comment: @matiaslauriti already edit my question sir..

Comment: @matiaslauriti are you there sir?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, your problem is that you are using the same action for 2 different routes, not only URL but also method.

Your fix would be:

```php
Route::post('/admin/usershiftpattern/search', 'Admin\UserShiftPatternController@update')
    ->name('usp.search');
```

See how I changed `@index` to `@update`. That should do it.

Comment: I already uppdate my question as your answer and got this error --> Creating default object from empty value

Comment: Which line of code is giving you this error ?

Comment: this line -->$usp_var->shift_pattern_id = $req->inputShiftPatternID;

Comment: Can you `dd` the variable `$usp_var` ? I think it is `null`

Comment: So, `$req->inputid` is empty, you are not sending that on your form. You have to validate that input first, you can also change `find` to `firstOrFail` so it will return with a 404 (because that ID does not exist).

Comment: how to validate that input sir?

Comment: Read [this entire documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation), I recommend you to use `FormRequest`s, but read that page I shared. If you have any doubts, create a new question with your new code (try something, and if it does not work, create a new question, do not edit this one), so if my answer worked for you, mark it as answered please